# Saving a variable from a UITextField

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7

I have been working on a little iOS application for a few hours, and have come across something I do not understand.

I am trying to have text in a UITextField to be saved as a variable, but no matter how many different ways I try, they never work. I have looked on this website, at least 11 other programming websites, forum pages, and have not found anything yet on it for xcode 7 and swift.

All of the ones I try come with an error, and there are so many different ways I have tried them, I don't want to post them all here.

Here is one of the ones I have tried.

```
    var secondscountdown = String(secondsCountField.text)
```

I get the error: Initialization of the variable 'secondscountdown' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it.

Thanks for your help in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Initialization of the variable 'secondscountdown' was
>   never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it.

This is a warning **(Not an error )** that is telling that you have assigned something to `secondscountdown` and you did not use this variable in any other places in your code. Therefore you should consider replacing the name of that variable `secondscountdown` with this `_`

In this line  `String(secondsCountField.text)` no need to convert the content of the textField to a String.

```
  let secondsCountDown = secondsCountField.text
```

**Note it is up to you to check if someone has input something into the textField, so check if you are getting data**

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I guess I just got a little scared when it told me that I needed to delete the variable. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`secondsCountField.text` is already `String?` so you do not need to pass it to `String` initializer. Just unwrap it:

```
var secondsCountdown = secondsCountField.text ?? ""
```

Error that you get is not error but warning. It says that your variable is assigned but not used anywhere.